# How to understand new Class.method(){some code} in android

Tags: java, android, callback, event-listener

I have seen this piece of code, it works but i dont understand this kind of structure. I mean, what is the second parameter doing (from new ..)?

I understand this:

```
new Class() = new Class.constructormethod();
new Class.anymethod(){} //?? how is it possible to add code between braces? What kind of Class ot patron admit this type of code injection?

setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: Are you sure that it is `new Class.anymethod(){}` and not `new Class.SomeNestedType(){}`?

Comment: I am not aware that either of your first two lines are valid Java syntax. If you have real-world examples of them, please use those, rather than made-up counterparts. The last example (`setNegativeButton()`) is using an anonymous inner class, per Mithun's comment.

Comment: The first two lines are justa a perception of the code below regarding my knowledge of using classes.  Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand what you meant in the first 2 lines.

If you are asking about the code in line 4, then,
what you are seeing is the instantiation of an [anonymous class.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

> The anonymous class expression consists of the following:
>
> - The new operator
> - The name of an interface to implement or a class to extend. In this
>     example, the anonymous class is implementing the interface HelloWorld.
> - Parentheses that contain the arguments to a constructor, just like a
>     normal class instance creation expression. Note: When you implement an
>     interface, there is no constructor, so you use an empty pair of
>     parentheses, as in this example.
> - A body, which is a class declaration body. More specifically, in the
>     body, method declarations are allowed but statements are not.
>
> Because an anonymous class definition is an expression, it must be
>   part of a statement. In this example, the anonymous class expression
>   is part of the statement that instantiates the frenchGreeting object.
>   (This explains why there is a semicolon after the closing brace.)

`OnClickListener` is not a method, but an interface in itself.

To help you understand it, the code is doing something similar to the following

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        class MyDialogInterface implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
             @Override
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //do something
             }
        }
        setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no,new MyDialogInterface());
    }

}

class DialogInterface {
    interface OnClickListener {
        public abstract void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which);
    }

}
```

In your code, instead of first declaring a new class that implements the OnClickListener interface and then instantiating it in the following line, you do it all in one single sentence.

This is often useful when you need an ad hoc implementation of a class or interface for a very specific section of code. You will typically see this on listeners and callbacks.

The bottom line is that you can always write

```
new MyInterface() { //implement abstract methods here }
```

instead of

```
   class MyIntefaceImplementation implements MyInterface { 
       //implement abstract methods here 
   }
   new MyInterfaceImplementation()
```

You can see in that, as it name suggests, the anonymous implementation has no named constructor that can be called elsewhere in the code other than where you define in.

You can instantiate anonymously classes derived from both classes and interfaces.

You can pass arguments to the parent class constructor between the parens

```
new ConstructorWithParams(params) {
   //implementation here
};
```

I hope that this helps.

Comment: Hello Patricio, thank you so much.  The two first lines is what i could understand of the code below it.  But, after reading your answer im wrong.  Another question is: if OnClickListener is an interface why do i have to use "()" in this sentence new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {?

Comment: Hello, I expanded my answer to address your question. You use the () to pass arguments to the parent class constructor. In the case of an interface, you just use the empty (), since they have no constructors by themselves.